# How to separate the contents that is placed side by side in an responsive website be separated by equal width?

Tags: html, css, drupal

While creating a single page responsive website in drupal7 ,after placing the two contents side by side that is about us and ethics within two blocks ,we are not able to separate /align the content to with equal width. There exists no spacing between the contents about us and ethics,even after setting "width=50%". How to set vertical spacing between two contents, so that it appears neat and understandable?

Comment: not enough info. Post your example.

Comment: How to give space in between two blocks in a responsive single page website in drupal 7? Example: we created two blocks about us and ethics in one row through drupal admin .We want to give vertical space between these two blocks!!

Comment: it's not an example, you didn't specify blocks. They can be inline elements and can be block elements. Diffirent solutions in diffirent cases

Comment: For us to help, we need to see the html and css you're using. Also, if the two "contents" are side by side, why do you need vertical spacing?

Comment: Side by side means there exists no spacing between the two blocks,they are joined together..here's our css and php code.. ..      /* css */
.container {width:100%}
.region1 {width:45%; 
padding-left:1em;
padding-right:1em;
float:left;
}
.region2 {width:45%;
padding-left:1em;
padding-right:1em;
float:left;}
.region3 {width:50%;
float:left}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.region1 {width:100%}
.region2 {width:100%}
.region3 {width:100%}

}

Comment: Our php code:   /* php */

<div class="container">
<?php if ($page['footer_first'] || $page['footer_second'] || $page['footer_third']): ?> 
    
      <div class="region1"><?php print render($page['footer_first']); ?></div>
      <div class="region2"><?php print render($page['footer_second']); ?></div>
      <div class="region3"><?php print render($page['footer_third']); ?></div>
    
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

Comment: Posting code in the comments section here = not helpful. Also, side by side literally means one on the left and one on the right. Therefor, vertical spacing wouldn't do you any good. Do you mean horizontal spacing?